# C# lambda expression to select elements

Tags: c#, lambda, functional-programming

I have a list of categories (string) and a list of objects of a certain type. I need to select from this list of objects only those which a property is in my list of categories.

I'm trying to use a lambda expression inside the `Where` method. I also tried to use the `in` operator but I got the following error messages:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

```
var entries = programmes.Where(x => x.Program.Name in categories);
```

I expect to return a sub-list with the objects which attribute Name is a member of my list categories.

Comment: `x => categories.Contains(x.Program.Name)`?

Comment: @juharr I tried that too! But it's not filtering, it's returning the whole list of objects :(

Comment: @JéssicaCarneiro can you post a sample data set with what you are getting at the output. Not seeing an issue off hand

Comment: You are probably want something like this:
`var entries = programmes.Where(x => categories.Any(w => x.Program.Name == w));`

Comment: What are the values in `categories`?  Are there any entries in `programmes` that have a `Program.Name` that isn't in `categories`?  Also what is `categories`, is it a `List<string>`?

Comment: @juharr the values in ```categories``` are strings. All entries in ```programmes``` will have the ```Name``` attribute as one of the values in ```categories```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Contains in this case

```
var entries = programmes.Where(x => categories.Contains(x.Program.Name)).ToList();
```

select only elements the x.Program.Name is in to categories list

Answer (score 1):

`var entries = programmes.Where(p => categories.Any(c => p.Program.Name == c));`

Should do it.

`categories.Any(...)` part checks to see if the specific string (in this case your program name) is found in the list of categories, returning a bool if it is found.

The `programmes.Where(p...)` part iterates through the items in programmes.

Put them together and you include in the entries enumerable any programs with a match.